Can't we use NEXT_PUBLIC env in the next.js approuter?
I am going to use both the client and server side google map api key and I added NEXT_PUBLIC to env of google map api key.
It causes error sometimes when I call that env at the server side and error message like this.
"Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported."
So can't we use NEXT_PUBLIC env on the server side at the next.js app router?

according to next.js docs ,Non-NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser.
therefore, you can use it on app router.
it seems your problem is elsewhere, can you share your code ?
